# Error accessing a website when the URL does not contain 'www'

Tags: dns, webserver, http, url

Why does the first link work, but the second one doesn't?
1. http://www.gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif
2. [gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif](http://gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif)

For the second link I get an error from my ISP:
http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/dnserror?url=http://www.gifgifgifgifgif.comgif/

What causes this? My browser, my ISP or the server (gifgifgifgifgif.com)?

My guess is that the server is misconfigured and only works if the URL contains www. Just a wild guess.

Comment: I notice this problem happening on Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, and Google Chrome; however, the second URL does not return an ISP error, just "INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND". Oddly enough, the URL is the interpreted as www.gifgifgifgifgif.comgif/11740.gif on Edge and Chrome, but not on IE. All the browsers I have used are up to date.

Comment: @AndrewLau - so, what is the conclusion?

Comment: What is the problem?
A link starts with the schema. within a page it's possible to just put // (and not http: before it, so link uses http or https depending of current used schema. <a href="//gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif"> should work fine, but <a href="gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif"> will open element gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif relative to current page.  If it's in a page located in http://mysite/location/page.html, this will point to http://mysite/location/gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif

Comment: more in detail https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: It is neither your browser nor your ISP; I see the same thing on Android Chrome on a US ISP.

Comment: @AntonyGibbs-This has nothing to do with a HTML page. The URL was simply inserted in a browser.

Comment: @AntonyGibbs I guess the problem described by OP is not related to absolute vs relative linking. I have also found this problem interesting. Just try to copy the 2nd link given by OP and paste it in your browser's address bar and hit enter. You will see the problem. Pretty Interesting

Comment: @AntonyGibbs - The problem described also occurs when I explicitly add the http:// - this is a problem with the way gifgifgifgifgif.com is redirecting urls that lack the www to www.

Comment: The added www is a permanent (301) redirect from http://gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif to http://www.gifgifgifgifgif.comgif/11740.gif.... there is a mistake in the nginx setting!! look for gifgifgifgifgif.comgif in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in incorrect configured server. If you try go to the second link with curl `curl -i http://gifgifgifgifgif.com/gif/11740.gif` you receive

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 28 Jan 2018 17:53:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 251
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.gifgifgifgifgif.comgif/11740.gif
```

So the browser redirects to the location URL, which is malformed.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted.      So error is not mine. What is now the best way to handle this error? I need to pass the URL as 'domain' + 'resource' to the InternetConnect API function. What is the best approach?

Comment: Try using `www.gifgifgifgifgif.com` as domain name. If that does not work I have no ideas.

Answer (score -1):

www.gifgifgifgifgif.com and gifgifgifgifgif.com are 2 different host names.  Resolution of host name to IP address is defined in the DNS.  If there is no DNS record for the second one, you would get a DNS error as you indicated.

www. is a convention only for hosts running web servers, it has no semantic meaning and is not mandated.

Comment: How does it relates to my question? What is the conclusion?

Comment: The conclusion is you cannot presume abc.com exists just because www.abc.com exists, and vice versa.  They are independent.  I couldn't see the posted error, but it said in the name it was a DNS error.

Comment: I doubt there are two DNS records for the same domain! The server is doing the redirect to www internal.

Comment: they aren't the same domain.  The 2 names are different and therefore need their own records.

Comment: just like google.com is not the same domain as .com.  You need to read up on DNS basics.  I've coded a DNS server and resolver, so I know a little bit.  www.x.com is a sub-domain of x.com and you could delegate it to someone else and sell it.  If the name isn't the same, it's not the same record / domain.

Comment: you mean that I can purchase www.google.com domain (let's suppose it is available) while Goolge own google.com?

Comment: yes.  How do you think people get azure sub-domains, or even .com sub-domains.  The registrar of .com allows sale of sub-domains.  There are plenty of providers who sell sub-domains 3, 4 levels deep and more.  The way it is done is with DNS delegation (e.g. delegate requests for sub-domains to your DNS or a DNS hosting service).  In the case of Google, they would still retain control over google,com, so they would still be in a position to cancel the delegation and cut you off, so not a great example.

Comment: it's basically the same principle.  Maybe a better example is something.azurewebsites.com.  None of this changes the original point.  www.abc.com and abc.com occupy different space in DNS config files, and there's never any guarantee that the existence of an A record for 1 implies the existence of an A record for the other.  They are 2 different records.